# Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys with angularjs umbraco plugin

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, umbraco7

I have an inherited site using Umbraco cms and angularjs. I am getting an issue with a google map component, the call looks like:

```
        assetsService.loadJs('https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=mykey')
        .then(function () {
            google.load('maps', '3',
                        {
                            callback: initMap,
                            other_params: 'libraries=places&sensor=false'
                        });
        });
```

mykey obviously is not my actual key, the actual key is an unrestricted one that I have created. I still get NoApiKeys error.

Is it because the URL I am calling is no longer supported?

Comment: Check network activity tab in your browser. What calls to Google Maps APIs you can see there? It looks like you might load an API twice. First time via `loadJs()` function with API key, second time via `google.load()` without API key. Try to use `other_params: 'libraries=places&key=YOUR_API_KEY'` in second call.

Comment: ok putting the key in the load call has fixed the issue, many thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

from xomena's comment i have added the key to load call:

```
assetsService.loadJs('https://www.google.com/jsapi')
    .then(function () {
        google.load('maps', '3',
                    {
                        callback: initMap,
                        other_params: 'libraries=places&sensor=false&key=mykey'
                    });
    });
```

all works fine now